# BigQuery to PowerBI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, google-analytics-4

Just want a thought as our Marketing team migrating to GA4 and they are saying that it doesn't have any connectors to PowerBI.They are thinking of using Windsor.Ai
Is there any other solution that I can connect GA4 to PowerBI?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Power BI plans to deliver the GA4 connector at the end of 2023 according to [this](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Google-Analytics-Concector-Support-for-GA4/td-p/3220898) discussion. Currently third party tools look like the only viable option.